# SqlCommand INSERT INTO from datagridview to SQL DB table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this code below which should save data from datagridview dtg_ksluzby to sql table `KLISLUZ`, but it says that:

> *Embedded statement cannot be declarition or labeled statemnt.*

```
for(int i=0; i< dtg_ksluzby.Rows.Count;i++)
    SqlCommand prikaz2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO klisluz'" + dtg_ksluzby.Rows[i].Cells["text"].Value +"', '" + dtg_ksluzby.Rows[i].Cells["pocet"].Value +"'",spojeni);
  prikaz2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: You're open for sql-injection. Use parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should **always** use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html), this kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Try like this;

```
for(int i=0; i< dtg_ksluzby.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    using(SqlCommand prikaz2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO klisluz VALUES(@p1, @p2)",spojeni))
    {
      prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dtg_ksluzby.Rows[i].Cells["text"].Value);
      prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", dtg_ksluzby.Rows[i].Cells["pocet"].Value);
      prikaz2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

As an alternative which Tim [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698884/sqlcommand-insert-into-from-datagridview-to-sql-db-table#comment25789611_17698951), you can reuse the same `SqlCommand` for your all values which you just need to use [`SqlParameterCollection.Clear()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method after you execute your command.

Like;

```
using(SqlCommand prikaz2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO klisluz VALUES(@p1, @p2)",spojeni))
{
    for(int i=0; i< dtg_ksluzby.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
          prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dtg_ksluzby.Rows[i].Cells["text"].Value);
          prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", dtg_ksluzby.Rows[i].Cells["pocet"].Value);
          prikaz2.ExecuteNonQuery();
          prikaz2.Parameters.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 ... or reuse the same `SqlCommand` and call `prikaz2.Parameters.Clear` first.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong (also use `Parametrized Queries`)

Fixed query:

```
"INSERT INTO klisluz values('" + dtg_ksluzby.Rows[i].Cells["text"].Value +"', '" + dtg_ksluzby.Rows[i].Cells["pocet"].Value +"')"
```

Fixed code:

```
using (SqlCommand prikaz2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO klisluz values('@val1', '@val2')",spojeni))
{
  for (int i = 0; i < dtg_ksluzby.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    prikaz2.Parameters.Clear();
    prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", dtg_ksluzby.Rows[i].Cells["text"].Value);
    prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", dtg_ksluzby.Rows[i].Cells["pocet"].Value);
    prikaz2.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Comment: I fixed his query and showed how to use parameters properly, there is nothing wrong with his loop, but I assume it would be better to answer fully :)